# How to import large amounts of data from CSV file to DataGridView efficiently

Tags: c#, csv, datagridview

I have 300 csv files that each file contain 18000 rows and 27 columns.

Now, I want to make a windows form application which import them and show in a datagridview and do some mathematical operation later.

But, my performance is very inefficiently...

After search this problem by google, I found a solution "A Fast CSV Reader".
(http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader)

I'm follow the code step by step, but my datagridview still empty.

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Could anyone tell me how to do or give me another better way to read csv efficiently.

Here is my code...

```
using System.IO;
using LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReadCsv();
}

void ReadCsv()
{
    // open the file "data.csv" which is a CSV file with headers
    using (CachedCsvReader csv = new
           CachedCsvReader(new StreamReader("data.csv"), true))
    {
        // Field headers will automatically be used as column names
        dataGridView1.DataSource = csv;
    }
}
```

Here is my input data:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28540219/20130102.csv

Thanks...

Comment: Should all the data to be processed at single shot? what is the performance now and what is expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do like

```
  private void ReadCsv()
    {
        string filePath = @"C:\..\20130102.csv";
        FileStream fileStream = null;
        try
        {
            fileStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
            return;
        }

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        bool isColumnCreated = false;
        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.Default).ReadToEnd()))
        {
            while (reader.Peek() != -1)
            {
                string line = reader.ReadLine();

                if (line == null || line.Length == 0)
                    continue; 

                string[] values = line.Split(',');

                if(!isColumnCreated)
                {
                    for(int i=0; i < values.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        table.Columns.Add("Column" + i);
                    }
                    isColumnCreated = true;
                }

                DataRow row = table.NewRow();

                for(int i=0; i < values.Count(); i++)
                {
                    row[i] = values[i];
                }
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
    }
```

[image]

Based on you performance requirement, this code can be improvised. It is just a working sample for your reference.

I hope this will give some idea.

Answer (score 1):

The data you provide contains no headers (first line is a data line). So I got an ArgumentException (item with same key added) when I tried to add the csv reader to the DataSource. Setting the `hasHeaders` parameter in the CachCsvReader constructor did the trick and it added the data to the DataGridView (very fast).

```
using (CachedCsvReader csv = new CachedCsvReader(new StreamReader("data.csv"), false))
{
     dataGridView.DataSource = csv;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Super fast ! Between first install: [LumenWorksCsvReader](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LumenWorksCsvReader)